# Servant consuming CSV API

Tags: api, csv, haskell, servant

I've found this walkthrough:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQB2JbxNEUI

and wanted to give it a go. I've found out however that my API returns CSV data, not JSON. What would be the alternative implementation for this piece of code ?

```
instance FromJSON GuardianResponse where
  parseJSON = withObject "response" $ \o -> do
    r <- o .: "response"
    t <- r .: "total"
    return $ GuardianResponse t
```

The API I want to consume comes from Alpha Vantage and is represented in the following way:

```
timestamp,open,high,low,close,volume
2018-09-05,111.0100,111.4200,108.1000,108.4900,28246869
2018-09-04,110.8500,111.9550,110.2200,111.7100,22557931
2018-08-31,111.6850,112.7770,111.5150,112.3300,23222713
2018-08-30,111.6700,112.6100,111.4400,111.9500,22798702
// ...
```

I've tried searching online, but looks like my knowledge on Haskell ecosystem is too small. Sorry - still learning hard :). So I'm happy to hear about useful sources of Haskell knowledge as well.

Comment: You can use [servant-cassava](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-cassava-0.10/docs/Servant-CSV-Cassava.html) to get a `CSV` content type instead of the `JSON` one you saw in that youtube video. May I also recommend [the official tutorial](https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/) which will walk you through content types among other things.

Comment: @AlpMestanogullari Sometimes websites set the `Content-Type` as `text/plain` instead of `text/csv` for `CSV` contents. How to deal with this situation with `servant-cassava`?

Comment: You'll want to define a custom `EncodeOpts` instance for which `csvContentType` will return `text/plain`. Let me know if you have a hard time figuring this out :)